# Regex: How do I capture a group after an optional capturing group using regular expressions?

Tags: python, regex, string

Suppose I have the following strings:

```
s1=u'--FE(-)---'
s2=u'--FEM(-)---'
s3=u'--FEE(--)-'
```

and I want to match F,E,E,M and the content of the parentheses in different groups.

I have tried the following regular expression:

```
u'^.-([F])([EF]*)([E]+)[^FEM]?(M*)?(\\(.*\\))?.*$'
```

This expressions give the following groups and spans for the different strings:

```
s1 -> 'F',(2,3)   ,   '',(3,3)    ,    'E',(3,4)    ,    '',(5,5)    ,    None,(-1,-1)
s2 -> 'F',(2,3)   ,   '',(3,3)    ,    'E',(3,4)    ,    'M',(4,5)   ,    (-),(5,8)
s3 -> 'F',(2,3)   ,   'E',(3,4)   ,    'E',(4,5)    ,    '',(6,6)    ,    None,(-1,-1)
```

For s2, I get the wanted behaviour, a matching of the contents of the parentheses, but for s1 and s3 I don't.

How do I create a regular expression that will match the content of the parentheses even if I don't have a proper match for the group containing 'M's?

EDIT:

The answer by DWilches resolved the initial issue using the regular expression

```
'^.-(F)([EF]*)(E+)[^FEM]??(M*)(\(.*\)).*?$'
```

However, the parentheses group is also optional. The following short python script clarifies the problem:

```
s1=u'--FE(-)---'
s2=u'--FEM(-)--'
s3=u'--FEE(--)-'
s4=u'--FEE-M(---)--'
s5=u'--FE-M-(-)-'
s6=u'--FEM--'
s7=u'--FE-M--'

ll=[s1,s2,s3,s4,s5,s6,s7]

import re
rr1=re.compile(u'^.-(F)([EF]*)(E+)[^FEM]??(M*)[^FEM]??(\(.*\)).*?$')
rr2=re.compile(u'^.-(F)([EF]*)(E+)[^FEM]??(M*)[^FEM]??(\(.*\))?.*?$')

for s in ll:
    b=rr1.search(s)
    print s
    if b:
        print " '%s' '%s' '%s' '%s' '%s' " % (b.group(1), b.group(2), b.group(3),     b.group(4), b.group(5))
    else:
        print 'No match'
    print '######'
```

For `rr1`, the output is:

```
--FE(-)---
 'F' '' 'E' '' '(-)' 
######
--FEM(-)--
 'F' '' 'E' 'M' '(-)' 
######
--FEE(--)-
 'F' 'E' 'E' '' '(--)' 
######
--FEE-M(---)--
 'F' 'E' 'E' 'M' '(---)' 
######
--FE-M-(-)-
 'F' '' 'E' 'M' '(-)' 
######
--FEM--
No match
######
--FE-M--
No match
######
```

It is OK for the first 5 strings, but not for the two last, since it requires the parentheses.

The `rr2`, however, adding `?` to `(\(.*\))`, yields the following output:

```
--FE(-)---
 'F' '' 'E' '' '(-)' 
######
--FEM(-)--
 'F' '' 'E' 'M' '(-)' 
######
--FEE(--)-
 'F' 'E' 'E' '' '(--)' 
######
--FEE-M(---)--
 'F' 'E' 'E' '' 'None' 
######
--FE-M-(-)-
 'F' '' 'E' '' 'None' 
######
--FEM--
 'F' '' 'E' 'M' 'None' 
######
--FE-M--
 'F' '' 'E' '' 'None' 
######
```

This is ok for `s1,s2,s3` and `s6`.

Some modification is needed to yield the desired output: getting the `M` if it exists and the content of the parentheses if the parentheses exist.

Answer (score 3):

It seems you need to use non-greedy operators:

```
^.-(F)([EF]*)(E+)[^FEM]??(M*)(\\(.*\\))?.*?$
```

Note that at the last of the last `.*` I added a `?`. And I also changed `[^FEM]?` for `[^FEM]??`.

In the first of your samples the problem was that that last `.*` was eating up this: `-)` while your `[^FEM]?` was eating up this: `(` ... thus not leaving anything for `(\\(.*\\))?`

(I also removed some square brackets around single letters, but that was more to have a shorter regex)

With this regex I obtain the following results:

```
--FE(-)---    ->     'F'    ''     'E'    ''     '(-)'
--FEM(-)---   ->     'F'    ''     'E'    'M'    '(-)'
--FEE(--)-    ->     'F'    'E'    'E'    ''     '(--)'
```

BTW: I will also remove the `?` at the end of `(\\(.*\\))?` because even if you don't put it there, a string that don't match that part will be consumed by the following `.*?`.

Comment: That's the question. The opening parenthesis is consumed by the `[^FEM]?` and the remaining string by the ending `.*`

Comment: This helps partly. However, the expression does not solve things like
    --FEE-M(--)-- or
    --FEM-(-)-

Comment: In my test using the pattern with `--FEE-M(--)--` yields: `'F' 'E' 'E' 'M' '(--)'` . What is the expected output then ?

Comment: Weird. To me it does not. Are you using python? If so, are you using any flags? To me `--FEE-M(--)--` yields `'F','E','E','',''`

Comment: Yes, I'm using python, no special flag. This is what I have: `m = re.search('^.-(F)([EF]*)(E+)[^FEM]??(M*)(\(.*\)).*?$', '--FEE-M(--)--')
print " '%s' '%s' '%s' '%s' '%s' " % (m.group(1), m.group(2), m.group(3), m.group(4), m.group(5))`

Comment: It seems that `?` after `(\(.*\))` makes a difference. I have updated the initial post.